# как в java script разбить массив на несколько массивов равной длинны

Tags: javascript, массивы

К примеру существует массив с числами

```
let array = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8' ];
```

Как его разбить на три массива равной длинны (третий массив содержит остаток чисел) и упаковать в родительский массив учитывая что длинна начального массива будет разная.

То есть должно получиться примерно такое:

```
let parrentArr = [
  ['1', '2', '3'],
  ['4', '5', '6'],
  ['7', '8'],
];
```

Comment: да, но у меня не получается это реализовать, у меня не математический склад ума и сложно продумать логику, я пробывал цикл фор но выходит какая то белиберда

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Array.prototype.chunk = function (n) {
    if ( !this.length ) {
        return [];
    }
    return [ this.slice( 0, n ) ].concat( this.slice(n).chunk(n) );
};

[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8].chunk(3);


// Output: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8]]
```